# Can a beam be expanded by Hermite-Gaussian modes having a different waist position?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, waves, laser

Hermite-Gaussian modes of propagating beam are expressed as
\begin{equation}
E_{l,m}(x,y,z) = E_0\frac{\omega_0}{\omega(z)}H_l\left(\sqrt{2}\frac{x}{\omega(z)}\right)H_m\left(\sqrt{2}\frac{y}{\omega(z)}\right)\exp\left(-\frac{x^2+y^2}{\omega^2(z)}-ik\frac{x^2+y^2}{2R(z)}-ikz+i(l+m+1)\eta(z)\right).
\end{equation}
The book I have says that these functions form a complete set of orthogonal functions, satisfying the following orthogonal relationship
\begin{equation}
\int\int E_{l_1,m_1}^*(x,y,z)E_{l_2,m_2}(x,y,z)dxdy = \delta_{(l_1m_1)(l_2m_2)},
\end{equation}
so that an arbitrary paraxial beam $E(x,y,z)$ can be expanded with these functions:
\begin{equation}
E(x,y,z) = \sum_{l,m}c_{lm}E_{l,m}(x,y,z).
\end{equation}
But it seems to me that the above $E(x,y,z)$ must have its beam waist at $z=0$, the same position as $E_{l,m}(x,y,z)$ has. My question is whether or not a beam the waist of which isn't at $z=0$ can be expanded by the above $\{E_{l,m}(x,y,z)\}_{l,m}$ having its waist at $z=0$. If can, show me why.